# Complex diagram

Tags: diagrams

I would appreciate if you help me draw the attached file.[image]

Comment: Have a look at tikz documentation, there is an example that can be adapted to your graph. I bet there are easier ways to do it in math mode btw.

Answer (score 6):

This is a starting point. Obviously my code is very simple and can be improved.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 &  \arrow[d, no head, dotted] &  &  \arrow[d, "\rho_2"] &  &  \arrow[d, "\rho_1"] \\
 &  \arrow[d] &  & \vartheta_{22} \arrow[d, "\rho_2"] &  & v_{12} \arrow[d, "\rho_1"] \\
 \arrow[r, no head, dotted] & \vartheta_{31} \arrow[r, "h_2"'] & v_{2\infty} \arrow[r, "f_{21}"'] \arrow[ru, "\overset{\vdots}{f_{22}}"] & \vartheta_{21} \arrow[r, "h_1"'] & v_{1\infty} \arrow[ru, "\overset{\vdots}f_{12}"] \arrow[r] & v_{11}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```